# Grab Monitor Info Powershell

Tags: powershell

So I've been playing around with this section of code I found but I'm unable to figure out how to get it into a function.

```
$Monitors = Get-WmiObject WmiMonitorID -Namespace root\wmi
        ForEach ($Monitor in $Monitors)
{
$Manufacturer = ($Monitor.ManufacturerName -notmatch 0 | ForEach{[char]$_}) -join ""
$MName = ($Monitor.UserFriendlyName -notmatch 0 | ForEach{[char]$_}) -join ""
$MSerial = ($Monitor.SerialNumberID -notmatch 0 | ForEach{[char]$_}) -join ""
Echo $Manufacturer
Echo $MName
Echo $MSerial
}
```

The Echo is in there just for testing but this works as is. Once I try placing it all into a function nothing is spit out. I'm also unsure on how to create an array so the data can be combined into one cell. An example would be monitor 1 + 2 serial cell 1, monitor 1 + 2 model cell 2.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have included your actual function so we could see why it wasn't working. That said, I generated this example which may help you:

```
function Get-MonitorDetails
{
  param
  (
    [Object]
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, ValueFromPipeline=$true, HelpMessage="Data to process")]
    $InputObject
  )
  process
  {
    $Manufacturer = ($InputObject.ManufacturerName -notmatch 0 | ForEach-Object{[char]$_}) -join ""
    $MName = ($InputObject.UserFriendlyName -notmatch 0 | ForEach-Object{[char]$_}) -join ""
    $MSerial = ($InputObject.SerialNumberID -notmatch 0 | ForEach-Object{[char]$_}) -join ""

    return [pscustomobject]@{
      Manufacturer = $Manufacturer
      MName        = $MName
      MSerial      = $MSerial
    }
  }
}

Get-WmiObject WmiMonitorID -Namespace root\wmi | Get-MonitorDetails
```

Comment: Would like to point out a flaw that was copied from the OPs code. This will drop all f,p and z's from the manufacturer, name and serial. `-notmatch 0` in theory is skipping spaces but it will drop bytes 70, 80 and 90. It should be `-ne 0` or `Where-Object{$_}` which would keep non zero numbers (since they evaluate to true). Or some better way to format the strings ...

Comment: Good catch @Matt